# AngularJS and Photo gallery implementation

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm SUPER frustrated after seeking around the web to look for at-least ONE better angularjs photo slider. In the end I found nothing.

This is my html snippet:

```
<div class="photo-viewer-container">
                            <div class="photo-viewer-slider">
                                <div class="photo-item-frame">
                                    <img class="photo-item" src="//c2.staticflickr.com/6/5026/5626106147_17f38c7070_n.jpg" alt="Kuala Lumpur"/>
                                    <img class="photo-item" src="//c2.staticflickr.com/8/7317/9127461653_1b9628e42c_n.jpg" alt="Kuala Lumpur"/>
                                    <img class="photo-item" src="//c2.staticflickr.com/6/5172/5452996951_d60655ea94_n.jpg" alt="Kuala Lumpur"/>
                                    <img class="photo-item" src="//c1.staticflickr.com/7/6201/6138711947_0476e0f62b_n.jpg" alt="Kuala Lumpur"/>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
```

I need a slider gallery implementation in AngularJS. Can be simple enough. The use of `blueimp` bring nothing much. Thanks!!

Comment: Why do you want to use AngularJS for a image slider?

Comment: @drakar So I can avoid jquery.

Comment: what about [ui.bootstrap.carousel](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap)

Comment: @macrog Thanks man!! Will give a try. On Google search there is no this option.

Comment: no probs, it's easy to implement, you have some samples over there you can refer to and check it in plunker ... I use it myself and it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try ui-bootsrap [carousel](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap)